# Anaconda is not starting up.

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, jupyter-lab

I just installed jupyterlab by typing this command in conda prompt

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

and then I tried opening up anaconda desktop app but I couldn't do it. I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",      line 636, in wrapper
return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",  line 706, in cmdline
ret = cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\exceptions.py", line 75, in exception_handler
return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 113, in start_app
if misc.load_pid() is None: # A stale lock might be around
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\misc.py", line 384, in load_pid
cmds = process.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 721, in cmdline
return self._proc.cmdline()
File "C:\Users\Vivek\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psutil\_pswindows.py",     line 639, in wrapper
raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=976)
```

Any idea why this is happening? Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run the application with `sudo` (or click `Run as Administrator` on your Windows machine). It could be a permissions issue.

This is most likely caused by the fact that your `anaconda-navigator` needs updating. This has been logged in [anaconda issue 1984](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1984) and [6006](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6006).

Try running the following command which will update your package:
`conda update anaconda-navigator`

If that still doesn't work, also call the application with the `--reset` flag as follows:

`anaconda-navigator --reset`.

Comment: I tried this too..
$ conda update anaconda-navigator
$ conda update navigator-updater

Still showing that error

Comment: Will try reset.

Comment: @VivekKulkarni Great!